# I tried the following code for XML data display as a table in HTML using JavaScript...But the browser(CHROME) refused to SHOW ANYTHING!!! Why is that?

Tags: javascript, html

This code shows text that is entered outside the  tags though.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>xmltest</title>
<style type="text/css">
            table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse:collapse;
            }
        th, td{
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    else
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","new1.xml",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
    document.write("<table><tr><th>STUDENT NAME</th><th>MATH</th><th>CHEMISTRY</th><th>PHYSICS</th></tr>");
    var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Student");
    for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
        {
            document.write("<tr><td>");
            document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0]);
            document.write("</td><td>");
            document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("maths")[0].childNodes[0]);
            document.write("</td><td>");
            document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("chem")[0].childNodes[0]);
            document.write("</td><td>");
            document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("phy")[0].childNodes[0]);
            document.write("</td></tr>");
        }
        document.write("</table>");
</script>
<p>this is visible</p>
</body>
```

can anyone say why the Table isn't visible?
I tried Validating the code..and it displays that its completely valid...
(The problem is in other browsers too...I checked all websites still didn't get a proper solution)

Comment: Don't use `document.write`.  And, you need to wait for the async response.

Comment: How do I give output without document.write?

Comment: Use the DOM APIs to create and append elements.

Comment: I would appreciate it more if you could give a code or something on how to do that...I am just a beginner